# space between <img> tags

Tags: html

if i use this code (with spaces between the two tags):

```
<img src="....." style="border:0px;margin:0px" />
<img src="....." style="border:0px;margin:0px" />
```

there are 4 pixels between images. if I use this:

```
<img src="....." style="border:0px;margin:0px" /><img src="...." style="border:0px;margin:0px" />
```

the space between images disappear, on all browsers!

Why????????

Comment: Any amount of blank space (aka white space) is rendered as one space character, probably its default width is 4 pixels. New line character is rendered as blank space as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<img src="http://www.nataliedee.com/111908/whatever-dude-whatever.jpg" style="border:0px;margin:0px;float:left;width:200px;" />
<img src="http://www.nataliedee.com/111908/whatever-dude-whatever.jpg" style="border:0px;margin:0px;clear:both;width:200px;" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JNWc7/

Comment: The question is WHY this happens (with an obnoxious amount of question marks). This does not answer that question.

Answer (score 13):

That's because white space is significant for inline elements. You can always float your images if you want to have them line up.

**Edit**: As requested, here is a simple example:

```css
/* This is used to "clear" the floated elements */
.images { overflow: hidden; width: 100% }

/* float the elements so that white space does not matter */
.images img { float: left; }
```

```html
<div class="images">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x100/000/fff&text=first+image" alt="first image" />
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x100/6aa8de/fff&text=second+image" alt="second image" />
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x100/ff6500/fff&text=third+image" alt="third image" />
</div>
```

Comment: float would avoid this issue, but floats have plenty of other quirks of their own. And won't solve the problem if he does actually want the images to be inline.

Comment: Plenty of quirks? Floating elements is pretty standard across all browsers.

Answer (score 6):

For the same reason that there is a space between the letters a and b in this paragraph:

```
<p>a
b</p>
```

Any kind of space in HTML is treated as a space (and collapsed into a single space).

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this is because HTML treats a new line character as white space, and white space is printed.

Answer (score 3):

There are so many good answers to this question, but I think there is chance this could be useful for anyone who will come to this in future.

`<img>` elements flow inline like text, but also have a width and height like block elements. In CSS, you can set an element to `display: inline-block` to make it replicate the behavior of images, so it would be nice to think of `<img>`s as `inline-block`s (browsers technically use `display: inline` but they are giving special treatment to images like `inline-block` elements).

So if you add a white-space like

- space
- tab
- newine

between them, a gap will appear.

Depending on the situation, you can use either of the following methods to get rid of the gap:

- Add a negative `margin-left`
- Use float
- Remove the **whitespace** between the elements, which can be done:

  1- Put theme in one line

  ```
  <img src="..."><img src="...">
  ```

  2- Removing the space

  ```
  <img src="..."><
  img src="...">
  ```

  3- Use HTML comments

  ```
  <img src="..."><!--
  --><img src="...">
  ```

  4- Skip the closing tag (in case there it is like `li`). (HTML5 only)

  ```
  <ul>
     <li>First
     <li>Second
  </ul>
  ```

  5- `font-size: 0` on parent element

Comment: `font-size: 0` is one of the cleverest ideas I've seen on SO. And has far fewer side effects than floating!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your newline is rendered as a space.

To avoid it, make sure there's no whitespace between your tags.
Here's what I usually do:

```
<img src="....." style="border:0px;margin:0px"
 /><img src="....." style="border:0px;margin:0px" />
```

Sure, it's ugly.  But it's the best way to deal with it.

Note about the other answers:  Floats have all kinds of different effects that you probably don't want (most importantly, they float next to your other content).  If you just want inline images, this is your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any text in that div with images, font-size:0; also fixes this issue