# How to remove this space among the pictures? CSS

Tags: html, css

[How to remove this space among the pictures?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdPr9.png)

I'm to learning to create a gallery, but I can't remove the space among the pictures, what should I do?

The code:

```css
body {
  background: #E6E6E6;
}
```

```html
<body class="imagens">
  <img src="imagens/imagem1.png">
  <img src="imagens/imagem2.png">
  <img src="imagens/imagem3.png">
  <img src="imagens/imagem4.png">
  <img src="imagens/imagem5.png">
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The space between the images is due to the whitespace between the `<img>` elements in your source code. By default, `<img>` elements have their CSS `display` property set to `inline`, meaning they act as emojis would in regular text (if you leave space between them, they will have space between them; if you don't leave space between them, they won't have any space between them).

So the HTML-based approach to solving this issue is to remove all whitespace characters between the elements:

```
<body class="imagens">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</body>
```

A CSS-based approach might be to apply something along these lines:

```
.imagens {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.imagens img {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float`.

```css
.clearfix::after, .container::after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
.images img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="images clearfix">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float: left` and make them `display: block`. No need for anything else...

```css
img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a small hack using HTML comments as spacers between the elements:

```
    <img src="imagens/imagem1.png"><!--
 --><img src="imagens/imagem2.png"><!--
 --><img src="imagens/imagem3.png"><!--
 --><img src="imagens/imagem4.png"><!--
 --><img src="imagens/imagem5.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix will be to set the below CSS property

Although I recommend not using this fix in the body element

```
.container{
   background: #E6E6E6;
   font-size:0px;
}
```

**Cause of the problem:** Source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220823/space-between-img-tags)

> because white space is significant for inline elements. You can always
>   float your images if you want to have them line up.

Since there is an enter between the images, we get this problem!

```css
.container {
  background: #E6E6E6;
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body class="imagens">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Marco Does this answer help you?